# Using Javascript to detect locale/timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone

Javascript provides us nice functions like `toLocaleString`, `toLocaleTimeString` etc. But I'm wondering - what is the right way to actually find out what the user's locale is, or at least their current time zone?

The use case I have in mind is I'm asking the user to *input* a date and time, and I want to construct a `Date` object from that but I need to know what time zone to use, since there's no standard function for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, the JavaScript doesn't have any timezone information, it has only current timezone offset (which is changing during DST).

So, you could use `new Date(2011, 10, 16, 15, 2, 0, 0).getTime()` to take current unix millseconds to determine precise instant of time using user's current timezone. However, if you need then convert it between different timezones, you should ask user's timezone explicitly and do conversions on server side.

Comment: Well hang on - does that 7-argument form of the `Date` constructor respect the user's time zone settings? If so, that's probably good enough for me.

Comment: In short, JS allows to manipulate dates only in user's timezone and convert an instant to the unix-mills. Everything else you should do on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get timezone: https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

Comment: Link from this 2012 answer is no longer valid.